# How to show arrow for direction of a person who is moving when we are getting its coordinate in google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am new to google map api and I have a particular use case where I am having coordinates(latitude and longitude) of a moving person and I want to show it in map along with direction, So far, I have tried this

- html file

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["map"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);
  function drawMap() {
  var arr = [
  ['Lat', 'Lon','data'],
  [12.938419, 77.62224, '0'],
  [12.938494, 77.622377, '0'],
  [12.938369, 77.622449, '0'],
  [12.938345, 77.622521, '0'],
  [12.938322, 77.622575, '0'],
      [12.938346, 77.622631, '0'],
  [12.938306, 77.622648, '0'],
  [12.938299, 77.622695, '0'],
  [12.938254, 77.622715, '0'],
  [12.938242, 77.622761, '0'],
  [12.938227, 77.622805, '0'],
  [12.93819, 77.622792, '0'],
  [12.938138, 77.622837, '0'],
  [12.938129, 77.622887, '0'],
  [12.938103, 77.622949, '0'],
  [12.938066, 77.622989, '0'],
  [12.938006, 77.622966, '0'],
  [12.937933, 77.623001, '0'],
  [12.937976, 77.623073, '0'],
  [12.937954, 77.623128, '0'],
  [12.937912, 77.623111, '0'],
  [12.937882, 77.623034, '0'],
  [12.937933, 77.623001, '0'],
  [12.938006, 77.622966, '0'],
  [12.937921, 77.62293, '0']
  ]
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
      map.draw(data, {showTip: true, showLine: true, mapType: 'normal', useMapTypeControl:true, enableScrollWheel:true});

  }
      </script>
          </head>
          <body>
          <div id="map_div" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
          </body>
          </html>
  ```

the output that I'm  getting is[image: here].

how can I show the direction in this code because in my real scenario I will have user coordinate only?

Comment: You can only guess the direction from the previous co-ordinates. There's nothing preventing them from turning at any point and then your arrow will be wrong until you have sufficient co-ordinates to point it the right way.

Comment: @Mansfield I m getting its continusous cordinate after every 5 second so I will be having its acurate location every time

Comment: @Mansfield I don't want to show arrow for every turn i want to show some arrow after a certain distance

Comment: I never said you wouldn't have an accurate location, you won't have an accurate **direction**, because co-ordinates don't have direction information. If all you're doing is guessing at the direction based on previous co-ordinates (what it sounds like) then you have no problem. What is your actual question here? (What are you hoping an answer will provide?)

Comment: @Mansfield ya My direction will be based on previous coordinate but what i am not able to figure it out is if in what i have done here just on looking screen you are not able to figure out starting and ending point so i want some arrow pointing towards ending showing like this is the starting and this is the ending or from where he has started and where he has ended

Comment: @Mansfield really thanks for taking interest in my problem, i tried one more thing see this link jsfiddle.net/9gJjj/138 here u are able to find starting and ending point but here its just taking the starting and ending cordinates and path it is deciding using google api here is there a way that entire path cordinates i can give like i am doing currently

or in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9gJjj/

the arrow are coming bu they are not proper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be achieved by using the visualization-API, because you must be able to draw the arrows on the map(but you don't have access to the google.maps.Map-instance at all).

With the maps-JS-API it's not hard to implement, by using a [`IconSequence`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#IconSequence) you may [draw symbols on a PolyLine](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineSymbols) , e.g. an arrow(which will be rotated automatically into the right direction)

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/V3gMT/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/V3gMT/)

Comment: Thanks Sir for your time and efforts this is exactly what i was looking for i am new to this Google API so just want to know this in this same fiddle is it possible to remove those red arrows and just show A at the starting and B at the ending and these arrow as they are coming now in the fiddle

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate your time and effort

Comment: thanks for your time sir i want to know if i am using the code that u suggested for commercial purpose than do i have to buy Google commercial license key for the purpose or can i use it as a open source tool